# "user_id" is empty when setting MyForm(data=data) (Django)

Tags: django, django-forms

I have the following model

```py
#models.py

class MyModel(models.Model):

    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete = models.CASCADE,null=True)
    link = models.URLField(max_length=2048)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(default = timezone.now)
    used = models.BooleanField(default = True)
```

and my form

```
class MyModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Wishlist
        exclude = [
            "user","date_added"
        ]
```

when I in my view try to "manually" create an instance (in the for-loop) and save it, the "user_id" in my database is NULL

```py
#views.py

def AddLink(request):
    user = request.user
    instance = MyModel(user=user)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = MyModelForm(request.POST,instance = instance)    
        if form.is_valid():
            link = form.instance.wishlist 
            used = form.instance.discount_pct
            
            #some util function to do some stuff
            res = my_util_func(link,api_key)
            for used, link in zip(res[0],res[1]):
                data = {"link":link,"used":used}
                form = MyModelForm(data=data)
                form.save()

            context = {
                "results":res} 
            return render(request, "discounttracker/myhtml.html",context=context)
```

I have tried changing `data` to `data = {"link":link,"used":used,"user":user}` and `data = {"link":link,"used":used,"user_id":user}` but it is still empty.

How can I add the user here?

Comment: How are you creating it "manually"? By the admin section?

Comment: No, in the view (in the for-loop)

Answer (score 0):

There is a secret option in `ModelForm.save()` called `commit` that allows you to not save the form right now, but instead return a model and insert some data into it. This should work perfectly here

```py
form = MyModelForm(data=data))
instance = form.save(commit=False)
instance.user = request.user
instance.save()
```

This sample inserts the currently logged in user into the `user` field on your model.

Comment: Thanks - my question is specific on how to add it via the `data` dict though.

Comment: Your form doesn't allow for that. As you yourself wrote, you are excluding `user` from form fields. Therefore, it can't be added through the `data` dict